# When does the canonical model structure on $\mathcal V$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ give a structure of monoidal model category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal V$ be a [closed symmetric monoidal model category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+model+category). It is well known that the category $\mathcal V$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ of $\mathcal V$-enriched categories is itself a closed symmetric monoidal category. The [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2134) by Berger-Moerdijk shows that in some cases $\mathcal V$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ admits the so-called *canonical model structure* (weak equivalences are Dwyer-Kan equivalences). Typical examples are obtained taking $\mathcal V = \mathbf{Set}$, $\mathcal V = \mathbf{sSet}$ or $\mathcal V = \mathbf{Ch}(k)$ (the category of complexes of $k$-modules). My question is the following:

> Are there reasonable hypothesis on $\mathcal V$ which ensure that $\mathcal V$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ is a closed symmetric monoidal model category?

The case $\mathcal V = \mathbf{Ch}(k)$ gives the known model structure on the category $\mathbf{dgCat}$ of dg-categories, and the homotopy category $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathbf{dgCat})$ is indeed a closed symmetric monoidal category - even if I actually don't know if $\mathbf{dgCat}$ is a monoidal model category (with the right compatibility conditions). Is a similar result reasonable also for $\mathcal V = \mathbf{sSet}$? I couldn't find any reference about internal homs in the homotopy category of simplicially enriched categories, even if I have in mind some possible candidates...

PS: this question is possibly related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178123/a-general-theory-of-quasi-functors-generalizing-from-dg-categories-to-mathcal).

Comment: For the case V = simplicial sets this model category has a name, it is the Bergner model structure on simplicially enriched categories. It is well-known that this model structure is not Cartesian (and hence is not a closed symmetric monoidal model category in the way you ask). A nice counter example is given in this MO answer http://mathoverflow.net/a/198310/184. However it is Quillen equivalent to Cartesian model categories, e.g. Quasicategories, and so the homotopy category still inherits a nice monoidal structure.

Comment: dgCat is also not a monoidal model category (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/195178/an-example-of-two-cofibrant-dg-categories-whose-tensor-product-is-not-cofibrant).

Comment: I can't think of *any* nontrivial monoidal model categories $\mathcal{V}$ for which the standard monoidal structure on $\mathcal{V}\text{-}\mathbf{Cat}$ makes it a monoidal model category.  (Of course, it is true in trivial cases like $\mathcal{V}=\mathbf{Set}$.)  The closest thing I know of is that for $\mathcal{V}=\mathbf{Cat}$, there is a different monoidal structure on $2\text{-}\mathbf{Cat}$ called the Gray tensor product that makes it a monoidal model category (http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~slack/papers/qmc2cat.html).